# Returning JSON object from rest API

Tags: json, django, reactjs, rest

I am attempting to return a json object from a rest API. I'm using django and when I view the object from the web, I can see the data as a json object:

```
[{"user": 2, "content": "please work", "members": [1], "date": "2017-11-04T21:44:23Z", "attendees": [2]}]
```

I am trying to receive it in react and then display the content from it:

```
export default class fetchPosts {
    constructor(props){
        this.state = {
        data: [],
        error: false,
        refreshing: false,
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/PostList',
        }
}
    fetchAllPosts = () => {
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/PostList')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                loading: false,
                data: response,
                refreshing: false,
            });
            console.log(data)
            return data
        })
}
}
```

but using the console log in my react debugger all that is returned is this strange [object.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzPyx.png) I understand that the console log may not display it precisely, however even when I attempt to deconstruct and render it, it tells me either the promise was rejected or data.content is null.

Answer (score 0):

You should try console.log(response) instead of console.log(data).